# Special linear matrix as exponential of traceless matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

Let $x\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, where 
$$ SL(n,\mathbb{R}) = \{X\in GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \mid \det X = 1\} $$
Show that there exists $X_a$ an asymmetric and $X_s$ a symmetric matrix with $\text{tr}(X_a) = \text{tr}(X_s) = 0$ such that $x = \exp(X_a)\exp(X_s)$.

So far I have considered $x^Tx$, and since this matrix is a real symmetric, positive definite matrix, I have been able to deduce $x^Tx = \exp(X)$ for a symmetric, traceless matrix. I do not see how to proceed from here though :(

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Might the polar decomposition of $x$ help? From what you have already done, you now only have to deal with the orthogonal part.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I am trying to follow your suggestion, but I don't think any orthogonal matrix can be realized as the image under $\exp$ of an antisymmetric matrix.

Comment: @MadsFriis Each *special* orthogonal matrix can be realized as the image under $\exp$ of an antisymmetric matrix, which should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Yes, I noticed that myself, and I too believe it is sufficient. Do you have an idea on how to prove this?

Comment: Not an idea of my own. I have found a proof in www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geombchap14.pdf where the surjectivity of the $\exp$ is stated in theorem 14.2.2.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why is only the case where $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal? $A$ can not be otherwise?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Why is only the case where $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal? $A$ can not be otherwise?

Comment: @Nash Sorry, I don't understand the question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Do not worry, I have already resolved that doubt, because $A=BC$ where $B$ is orthogonal and $C$ is symmetric. But I still have several doubts, for example, why does the symmetric $X$ found in the post meet that $tr(X)=0$? and why does the antisymmetric matrix $T$ found in the response of Boyobe meet that $tr(T)=0$? Thank you!

Comment: @Nash Two observations: $\det\exp X=\exp\operatorname{tr} X$, and *any* antisymmetric matrix has trace zero (because its entire diagonal is zero).

Answer (score 1):

A great comment of @Harald_Hanche-Olsen is seems to be proper solution. You already showed, that in case of a symmetric matrice the problem is done. So consider $A$ to be a orthogonal matrix. It is a well known fact, that any orthogonal matrix is $exp(T)$, where $T = -T^{T}$. Last fact can be proved by using spectral decomposition of orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Considering the last sentence: what do you mean by "spectral decomposition of orthogonal matrix"?

Comment: @Byobe 
Why is only the case where $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal? $A$ can not be otherwise?

Comment: @Byobe Why $tr(T)=0$?